# Why my checking tooltip for blank input is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have input box with tooltip. The tooltip should be appear then user does not fill all the inputs. So the tooltip is working when user left blank. But the problem is the button cannot be submit/click. Cannot proceed to ajax.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="editName">

$('#editName').tooltip({trigger:'manual', title:'Enter Name', placement:'right'});

$('#btnSubmit').on('click',function(){

    var checkfieldvalue = true;

    $('#editForm input').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            $(this).tooltip('show');
            checkfieldvalue = false;
            $(this).on('focus', function(){
                $(this).tooltip('hide');
            });
        }
    });

    if (checkfieldvalue){
     .... // will proceed to Ajax
    }

});
```

Comment: your button is `<input type="submit" />`?

Comment: <button type="button" >

Comment: some input will have a falsy value and therefore it enters the conditions